# Powershell Script to extract Outlook .msg files Data and Rename .msg file using Msg data (e.g. Date Sent, Topic)

Tags: powershell

Newby to Stackoverflow so apologies if this request is in the wrong location.

I'm also new to PowerShell and have been researching a solution that appears to be offered by PowerShell. My lack of experience has left me unable to modify an example script so I'm here looking for help.

My objective is to rename many outlook .msg files, located in folders and sub-folders, using data extracted from each .msg file. In my case, I require the date sent (Senton) (and topic, but less important). This is currently, and painfully, being done manually and takes a long time so I thought we needed something to semi-automate a solution.

I've searched around on various forums and blogs and have found a script that seems to be heading towards what I want (details below) but I just don't have the skills to do the last bit of taking the Sent Date and changing the .msg filename. I've attempted various piping solutions referring to variable $msg.Senton. The PowerShell debugger indicates that the line with comment "My code changes" have good values but produces an error (relating to parameter NewName) for each object iteration (see below).

Any help in making progress will be appreciated. In the mean time, I'll continue experimenting with the debugger.

The script was sourced from this (http://jon.glass/blog/reads-e-mail-with-powershell/) site and the script looks like...

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\higginsr4\Test\StudyExamples\SmallMsgFolder" -Filter *.msg|
ForEach-Object{
    $outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
    $msg = $outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate($_.FullName)
    $msg | Select senderemailaddress,to,subject,Senton,body|ft -AutoSize
    $msg | Rename-Item -NewName { $msg.Senton + $_.name} ## My code changes
    }
```

PowerShell debugger error...

> Rename-Item : The input to the script block for parameter 'NewName' failed. Cannot convert argument "1", with value: "", for "op_Addition" to type "System.TimeSpan": "Cannot 
>   convert null to type "System.TimeSpan"."
>   At My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\GetEmailDetails\RobsGetEmailDetails.ps1:6 char:33
>   +     $msg | Rename-Item -NewName { $msg.Senton + $_.name}
>   +                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.__ComObject:__ComObject) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptBlockArgumentInvocationFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise but if further details are required then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to be highlighted in what you have tried:-

1. `$msg` is a ComObject created by by the base type `System.MarshalByRefObject` and not an actual physical file. Hence, you are sort of deviating from your objective there.
2. You are including the `-NewName` parameter in a script block. Note that, you have already done that when you piped the output of `Get-ChildItem` to `Foreach-Object`. Hence, the extra script block is redundant.

You can do something like this -

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\higginsr4\Test\StudyExamples\SmallMsgFolder" -Filter  *.msg |
ForEach-Object{
    $outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
    $msg = $outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate($_.FullName)
    $msg | Select senderemailaddress,to,subject,Senton,body|ft -AutoSize
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName "$($_.Basename)_$($msg.Senton.ToString('ddMMyy')$($_.Extension)"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Vivek. I'm still getting debug errors below. Seems to imply file to be renamed does not exist. Any ideas?.............

Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'C:\Users\higginsr4\Test\StudyExamples\SmallMsgFolder\06327 – Corros – MHRA Application Documents Requested  -  [yyyy-mm-dd].msg' 
does not exist.
At \\nuth-rnas01\home37\Departmental Home Drives\H\HigginsR4\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\GetEmailDetails\RobsGetEmailDetails.ps1:7 char:5
+     Rename-Item -path $_.FullName -NewName "$($msg.Senton.ToString('ddmmyy') + ' ...
+ ...

Comment: Small Correction @vivek. `'ddmmyy'` should be `'ddMMyy'`. Otherwise it worked perfectly.

Comment: Hi Vivek, I still have a debug error. Changed code line 6 to **** Rename-Item -path $_.FullName -NewName "$($msg.Senton.ToString('ddMMyy') + '_' + $($_.name))" ****, but debug error is now *****Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'C:\Users\higginsr4\Test\StudyExamples\SmallMsgFolder\06327 – Corros – Amendment - Sponsor classification required  -  
[yyyy-mm-dd].msg' does not exist.
At \\<removed some path here>\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\GetEmailDetails\RobsGetEmailDetails.ps1:7 char:5
+     Rename-Item -path $_.FullName -NewName "$($msg.Senton.ToString('ddMMyy') + ' ...

Comment: @RohinSidharth - Thanks. I corrected it. I was taking minute attribute.
Does the file actually exist? Have you verified that?
Try `Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName` instead of `Rename-Item -path $_.FullName`

Comment: Yes. that fixed it! many thanks for your help. Works an absolute treat, Cheers

Comment: Is there one last aspect of filename formatting that you can help me with? I really need the Send Date to be at the end of the filename. e.g. "filename.msg" becomes "filename_<send date>.msg" but unsure as to how to add the "-replace" option into the command line. I'll continue trying it myself with the debugger...

Comment: Actually managed to do it myself with some guesses and using the debugger. Added a new line to simplify building the filename string I require followed by a modified replace line. i.e. ********$MyString=' - '+$msg.Senton.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')+'.msg'******* and then
************    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName "$($($_.name) -replace '.msg',$MyString)" *********

Comment: You don't need to use the `-replace` parameter. You can switch positions in the `Rename-Item` cmdlet itself. Take a look at the modifications.